# MySQL index for ORDER BY A*B

Tags: mysql, sorting, query-optimization, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB table with two `INT` columns, say `col1` and `col2`. I'd like to add an index that will allow me to:
`SELECT * from myTable WHERE col0=5 ORDER BY col1*col2 DESC`
Is it possible to have an index that will support such a sorting or will i need to add a column that keeps that value (`col1*col2`) ?

Comment: I don’t think so. Indexes are column only, and not for storing expressions.

Comment: Why would you need an index for this?

Comment: Possibly an index would be used from the WHERE clause, if there's one on `col0`. If the query doesn't return too many matches, the `a*b` sort will not hurt.

Comment: @Strawberry @Jonny You're both right that if the `WHERE` doesn't return too many matches the sort won't hurt, but it does (in the C*100k range)

Comment: Noam, see [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html). If there's a WHERE-clause, that utilizes `key1`, `key2` possibly can't be used for sorting. Only `key1` or eventually parts of `key1`. Maybe works, to put the `col1*col2` in another column, but put one index on `col0` AND `order_col`. Check with EXPLAIN SELECT...

Answer (score 2):

Noam, see [ORDER BY Optimization‌​](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html). If you want to use the index for sorting, it should be the same as the index, that is used in the WHERE clause and of course the value for sorting needs to be stored in it's own column. [Here I generated a test table with 100k rows](http://pastebin.com/Tgks8vCP), that should match your situation.

---

1.) Adding **ONE INDEX** on two columns (this works for utlizing an index for both select and sort):

```
ALTER TABLE `test_data` ADD INDEX super_sort (`col0`,`sort_col`);
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test_data` WHERE col0 = 50 ORDER BY sort_col;
```

key -> super_sort; Extra -> **using where**
(index is used for WHERE and SORT)

---

2.) Adding two indexes, one for WHERE and one for SORT (won't work)

```
ALTER TABLE `test_data` DROP INDEX `super_sort`;
ALTER TABLE `test_data` ADD INDEX (`col0`);
ALTER TABLE `test_data` ADD INDEX (`sort_col`);
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test_data` WHERE col0 = 50 ORDER BY sort_col;
```

key -> col0; Extra -> **Using where; Using filesort**
(an index is used for WHERE, BUT NOT for sorting)

---

So the answer is: Yes, you will need a column, that keeps that value `(col1*col2)` AND you need ONE index on both columns: `col0` (for the WHERE-clause) + `sort_col` (for sorting) like in first example. As soon, as you `ORDER BY` any calculation (e.g. `col1*col2`) no index can be used for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

You can add new column that contains the value of `col1*col2` and use it for sorting. Otherwise you can use `SELECT * from myTable WHERE col0=5 ORDER BY col1*col2 DESC`.

Comment: What is the reason for that column?

Comment: i mean both ways are working, but keeping new column will make it faster when reading from thousands rows, and it has storage issue, when storing data with new column.

Comment: You’re still not explaining why your answer is the correct one; the question itself states this as possibility, but the question asks whether this is needed, or if some kind of index could be used instead.

Comment: You could, though, introduce some kind of other method, if you know it, that would be even faster.

Comment: Also please use proper code blocks and grammar, if possible.